# Control step level execution in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions

Is it possible to execute a step or skip it and proceed to next step depending on some condition in spring batch. 
E.g. there are 5 steps in a batch job, and before every step execution we need to check whether to skip it or not depending on value of a column in database.
Requirement is to create a generic logic either through listeners or an other way that can control the step executions at run time?

I need to populate the next attribute at runtime. Sample xml:

```
    <batch:step id="step1" next="stepdecision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2" next="stepdecision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step3" next="stepdecision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step4" next="stepdecision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:decision id="stepdecision" decider="decider">
        <batch:next on="next" to="#{jobExecutionContext[nextStep]}" />
    </batch:decision>

</batch:job>

<bean id="decider" class="com.bmo.apms.batch.StepFlowDecider">
</bean>
<bean id="tasklet1" class="com.bmo.apms.batch.TestTasklet" />
```

But it is throwing exception:
**Configuration problem: The element [step2] is unreachable|**

I think spring doesn't allow to bind next attribute at run time.
Please advice.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this b creating a decider that finds the next step.
Every step's next attribute is he decider which forwards it to the actual the step at run-time.

```
    <batch:decision id="stepdecision" decider="decider">
        <batch:next on="step1" to="step1" />
        <batch:next on="step2" to="step2" />
        <batch:next on="step3" to="step3" />
        <batch:next on="step4" to="step4" />
        <batch:end on="end" />
    </batch:decision>


<batch:next on="step3" to="step3" />
        <batch:next on="step4" to="step4" />
        <batch:end on="end" />
    </batch:decision>

    <batch:step id="step1" next="stepdecision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2" next="stepdecision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step3" next="stepdecision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step4" next="stepdecision">
        <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1" />
    </batch:step>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't configure the next value at runtime.  Configure what the `Decider` will return at runtime.  That's the whole point of a decider.